# Drop a column from a temporal table

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I'm trying to drop a column from a temporal table but still keep the data in the history.
Simply using alter drop will delete the column from the history table as well so it won't do.

I've tried to set the system_versioning = off, drop it and then return it to be on but its creating a new history table and all the previes history is gone (I can't define the old history table to be the current because it contained another column - the one that I dropped).
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Drop the column from the old history table also, then use `HISTORY_TABLE =` would seem the obvious thing to try.

Comment: The definition of the 2 tables needs to be the same, so if you do "need" to `DROP` the column you have to do it in both. Why not `NULL` all the values in the non-history table (and set it to be `NULL`able if it isn't), and then you can simply omit the column in your code (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`,etc statements) going forwards.

Comment: I want to save the data that in the column I dropped, is there a way to keep it in the history table? I need to know what changed in the table and if someone dropped a column I need to know it and what was in it.

Comment: That's a *different* question, @Ester . Ideally your deployment workflows should already be recording who is deploying (or committing) your DDL changes and you'll be able to see who did *what* in your source control. What are you really asking here? How to "drop" a column in a temporal table and retain the values, or how to tell who did a DDL change?

Comment: @ThomA I want to know how to drop a column and still have the data that was in it. As I said, I can't see a way to drop it but still have it in the history.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments the two tables (the "live" and history table) must have the same definitions. If you `DROP` a column from the "live" table it is `DROP`ed from the history table.

As such, if you want to retain that data *don't* `DROP` it. Instead `UPDATE` all the values to `NULL`, which might need an `ALTER` on the column to make it `NULL`able (and you may need to drop some `CONSTRAINT`s). Then you just omit the column in your workflows going forwards, unless you need it when querying the history table:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create history schema if needed.
--Note, I do not clean this up at the end.
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM sys.schemas 
               WHERE name = N'history')
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA history;';
GO
--Create sample table with history table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourID int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_YourPK PRIMARY KEY,
                            SomeDate date NOT NULL,
                            ToBeDropped varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                            SomeOtherValue varchar(20) NULL,
                            ValidFrom DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
                            ValidTo DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
                            PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo))
    WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = history.YourTable));
GO
--SAmple data
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeDate,
                           ToBeDropped,
                           SomeOtherValue)
VALUES(GETDATE(),'abc123','asdvaksd'),
      (GETDATE()-1,'def123','sdfgdfgfg'),
      (GETDATE()-2,'xyz456','assdvaksdfgsd'),
      (GETDATE()+1,'abc789','fgfghgfjgfjgfh');
GO
--Check data
SELECT YourID,
       SomeDate,
       ToBeDropped,
       SomeOtherValue
FROM dbo.YourTable;

GO
--Make some changes
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ToBeDropped = 'qwe654'
WHERE YourID = 2;

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ToBeDropped = 'asd456',
     SomeDate = GETDATE() + 3
WHERE YourID = 3;
GO
--Check data again
SELECT YourID,
       SomeDate,
       ToBeDropped,
       SomeOtherValue
FROM dbo.YourTable;

SELECT YourID,
       SomeDate,
       ToBeDropped,
       SomeOtherValue,
       ValidFrom,
       ValidTo
FROM history.YourTable

GO
--Change column to NULLable (if needed)
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN ToBeDropped varchar(10) NULL;
GO
--UPDATE all rows to NULL
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ToBeDropped = NULL;
/*
If you have a DEFAULT constraint on the column in the table, you'll need to
DROP that CONSTRAINT as well to ensure that they have the value NULL in
future INSERT statements.
If you have any CHECK CONSTRAINTS that reference the column too, you'll likely
need to ALTER/DROP those as well.
*/
GO
--Add a new row, old column now omitted
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeDate,
                           SomeOtherValue)
VALUES(GETDATE()+7,'asdkjb65'); --Only 2 columns
GO
--SELECT, with column omited
SELECT YourID,
       SomeDate,
       --ToBeDropped,
       SomeOtherValue
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
--History with column included
SELECT YourID,
       SomeDate,
       ToBeDropped, --Can still be returned
       SomeOtherValue,
       ValidFrom,
       ValidTo
FROM history.YourTable;
GO
--Clean up
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);

DROP TABLE history.YourTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

Comment: You're welcome, @Ester . Rather than posting a "thank you" comment though, which is likely to be removed as "no longer needed", please do take a moment to have a read of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) As you haven't taken the [tour] yet too, which you were suggested to when you signed up, you might want to have a read of that too.